# Java Logg handling class with exceptions

Tags: java, logging

I have two classes GetStatus and Logg.

GetStatus reads from an xml-file and picks two elements and checks if there value are right or wrong. We have try and catch in GetStatus and some exceptions.

```
  } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "wrong or interrupted I/O operations.",ex);
    }catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Wrong argument format", ex);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Indicates a serious configurationerror",ex);
    } catch (SAXException ex) {
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "XML Parsing error", ex);
```

We want to ship the exceptions to another class, and create a file and logg the exceptions. But we want to choose if exceptions must logg or just print out to the terminal or consol. We want to do this with java.util.logging.

This is our Logg class

```
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");

    if (saveMethod == 1) {
        try {
            fh = new FileHandler((dateFormat.format(date) + ".log"), false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Wrong in Logg", e);
            Logger l = Logger.getLogger("");
            fh.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
            l.addHandler(fh);
            l.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        }
    }
        else{
            System.err.println("You have not chosen save method!");
        }
        return 0;
```

At the moment it creates a file every time.

Answer (score 0):

It might be creating a new file every time because you are giving it a different file name every time (as it is based on the current time).

Is there any reason why you cannot have a static "LOGGER" field, for example...

```
public class MyClass {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);

    ...
}
```

I assume you are using Log4J 1.2? If so, you can configure that to use a file appender that will create a new log file every day. See this link...

http://blog.moes.as/2008/10/example-of-using-dailyrollingfileappend.html

Comment: We want a new file every time we run the program. I think we are using java.util.logging.